# Why do some applications have two icons in /usr/share/application?

Tags: 14.04

[image: please help me why same application have two icon.]

In this image, why do [Rhythmbox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rhythmbox/) and Software Update have two icons?

Is there something wrong with my system?

Comment: Do you have more than the default number of desktop environments installed? Post the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions`. Do so by editing your question.

Comment: Did you *upgrade* your system (no fresh install)?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm I find your question to be interesting as I intend to do a version upgrade myself. Are you implying that such duplicates can occur after a distribution upgrade? Makes me think...

Comment: no i didn't. i installed ubuntu few days ago. today when i check this folder i am seeing this. @DKBose

Comment: yes i upgrade my system. @jacob . no fresh install mean??

Comment: @CristianaNicolae Theoretically, on an upgrade, old versions of applications are replaced, and so their corresponding `.desktop` files. In  reality however, things occasionally go wrong. Software Center is a good example of that; on an upgrade, many users had two versions of it on their system. Some applications however have multiple `.desktop` files, like nautilus. I always prefer fresh installs, also to prevent issues with local files.

Comment: There is no issue, and this is perfectly normal, even for a completely new install.

Comment: @dobey like i mentioned, *Some applications however have multiple .desktop files*. Not in the case of Software & Updates though, not on my system that is.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't know about "your system" but there are two different .desktop files installed by default for that, one from _software-properties-gtk_ and one from _app-install-data_.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's nothing wrong with your system.

### The duplicated launcher icons explained:

The different icons are different commandline options.  Some context applications with call the associated *.desktop icon.  The exec option of the icon will depend on how the application is called.

Some of the Icons you show in your image may be obvious because of the difference in the way they are named.  You can see the difference in the way the app is called by right clicking and clicking on properties to see other differences.

Some of the `*.desktop` files have a `%U` argument, used so the application will accept arguments.

Some of the Launchers are different commands that are called differently and are named differently often by a symbolic link.

Some exampes from the list in you image are:

```
Name: Online Accounts
Command: unity-control-center credentials

Name: Online Accounts
Command: Online account credentials and settings

Name: Personal File Sharing
Command: gnome-file-share-properties

Name: Rhythmbox
Command: rhythmbox %U

Name: Rhythmbox
Command rhythmbox-client --select-source %U
```

### The specific **Rhythmbox** and **Software Update** icons:

In the particular cases of the **Rhythmbox**.  The icons are provided for the specific method it'll be called in context-sensitive usage by the command.  This is consistent with most of the launchers.

In the particular case of the **Software And Update** launcher, those two are installed by different packages.  They also have different file names:

```
software-properties-gnome.desktop package source  app-install-data
software-properties-gtk.desktop   package source  software-properties-gtk
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looking directly at the file system contents via the file manager, which does not fully follow the XDG Desktop File specification for presenting these files for viewing.

Rhythmbox has a secondary .desktop file which is for a secondary service, and this file specifies it should be hidden from menus, however you are looking directly at a few of the file system, and not of the menus.

Likewise, the Software Properties tool has a couple of .desktop files for running it slightly differently under different environments, and the secondary one specifies it should be hidden from menus. But you are not looking at a menu.

This is not a problem, and completely normal, even for a completely new install of Ubuntu, or most any Linux distribution really.