# Duplicates in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-installation, updates, software-center

In Ubuntu Software there are duplicates listed for some applications like: Calendar; GNOME Software; ImageMagick; Online Accounts; Software & Updates; UXTerm/XTerm.

I believe they should not be listed twice as most other applications aren't.

My system is a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04. Is there a good reason for this issue with Ubuntu and does anyone else encounter it?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` then check it again.

Comment: some packages are used in more than one desktop and need to be tweeked for that environment (ie, kde vs gnome)

Comment: That's explained here: [Why do some applications have two icons in /usr/share/application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898474/why-do-some-applications-have-two-icons-in-usr-share-application/898487#898487).

Comment: I have same question when I start serach in ubuntu software in example VLC
then I found two results. One VLC is from SNAP and other VLC is from ubuntu-bionic-updates-universe. 
Is there any fundamental difference?
I noticed that in Snap has up-to-date versions of the applications.